# Missing data ajax sent server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Use ajax to create user but data sent API is Null.
My code:
javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btncreate", function () {

    var user = {
        name="myname",
        id= 1
    };
    console.log(user); // have data
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44344/api/user/create",
        type: "POST",
        data: {userRequest: user}, //miss data send server
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data),
        }
   });

});
```

Code API

```
Create(CreateRequest userRequest) //userRequest is null
```

Debug code user alway have data but when send to Web-API data will null. I don't know reason

Comment: So sorry: name="myname",  id= 1. My code is jquery get data form. This is error when is change code. ``` Name: $("#createname").val(),
                    Id: $("#createid").val(),```

Comment: What exactly is your error? You can try adding an `error` callback and inspect the error message.

Comment: data ajax have value, but sent data to api "userRequest" is null variable. success: return error of Entity framework (value cannot convert), exactly parameter is null

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you getting a `null` value on server side? If so, please post the code of your API. Also, are you sure that your `user` object is sent correctly to the server? Have you tried to check this through your browser's network inspector?

Comment: api code `[Route("api/user/create")] public PageResult Create(CreateRequest userRequest){ \\ action} `: when debug para receive data from client with property is null(example: user: null, id: null), code javascript log (user: sa, id: 123). I don't know reason.